# table multirow- multicolumn

Tags: tables

I have a problem with this table: I need to merge the 3 columns and I don't know how many rows at the bottom to make a unique cell  the contains the final text that is quite long. As I did it doesn't work. Moreover, if possible I'd prefer to have bold lines to replace the 2 \hline.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Table1}\\ 
\hline
 & $Y_i_t$ & $I_i_t$\\
 \hline
 \hline
  $Turnout_i_t&-7.02**$&$-0.001***$\\
 \hline
 & (3.025) & (0.000)\\
 \hline
 Compulsory voting dummy_i&$-1865.053***$&-0.490\\
 \hline
  &(279.417)&(0.632)\\
\hline
Net exports_i_t&0&0\\
\hline
&(0.000)&(0.000)\\
\hline
Urban population_i_t&0&\\
\hline
&(0.000)&\\
\hline
Net oda received_i_t&$-4.513**$&\\
\hline
&(1.902)&\\
\hline
gini_i_t&$-14.456**$&\\
\hline
&(6.10)&\\
\hline
\alpha_i&yes&yes\\
\hline
\gamma_t&yes&yes\\
\hline
constant &yes**&yes**\\
\hline
\hline
N&164&164\\
\hline
T&21&21
\hline
R^2 within country&0.54&0.5\\
\hline
\rho (Fraction of \sigma_e due to \alpha_i)&0.920&0.815\\
\hline
\hline
\\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{The displayed standard errors are robust and clustered at country level. Level of statistical significance of coefficients:***$(1%), **(5%), *(10%)$}}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i)  please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`; (ii) for bold lines see `booktabs` package; (iii) what you like to merge is not very clear (sorry)

Comment: and your code has many (to many) errors. please make it compilable.

Answer (score 2):

i suspect that you like to obtain a table as shown below:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout). Since you not provide minimal working example (a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` ans ending with `\end{document}`) exist height probability that i misinterpreted your code. the difference is probably also in the perception of the aesthetic appearance of the tables ...

body of table in my mwe is:

**edit**:
apparently op is not interested to help me to complete/adopt my answer to his/her document...

anyway for anyone who might be interested for complete mwe, which generate above shown table:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \sisetup{input-symbols = ( - ),
              table-space-text-pre=(,
              table-space-text-post = ***,
              table-align-text-post=false,
              group-four-digits,
              table-format=-4.3}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table 1}
    \label{tab: my important table}
\begin{tabular}{r
                S[table-format=-4.3] 
                S[table-format=-1.3]
                }
    \toprule
                & {$Y_{i_t}$}           & {$I_{i_t}$}       \\
    \midrule
Turnout $i_t$   & -7.02\tnote{**}       & -0.001\tnote{***} \\
                & (3.025)               & (0.000)           \\
    \addlinespace
Compulsory voting dummy $i$
                & -1865.053\tnote{***}  &-0.490             \\
                & (279.417)             & (0.632)           \\
    \addlinespace
Net exports $i_t$
                &   0                   &   0               \\
                & (0.000)               & (0.000)           \\
    \addlinespace
Urban population $i_t$
                &   0                   &                   \\
                & (0.000)               &                   \\
    \addlinespace
Net oda received $i_t$
                & -4.513\tnote{**}      &                   \\
                & (1.902)               &                   \\
    \addlinespace
gini $i_t$      & -14.456\tnote{**}     &                   \\
                & (6.10)                &                   \\
    \addlinespace
$\alpha_i$      &   {yes}               &   {yes}           \\
$\gamma_t$      &   {yes}               &   {yes}           \\
constant        &   {yes\tnote{**}}     &   {yes\tnote{**}} \\
    \midrule
N               &   {164}               &   {164}           \\
T               &   {21}                &   {21}            \\
    \midrule
$R^2$ within country
                & 0.54                  & 0.5               \\
$\rho$ (Fraction of $\sigma_e$ due to $\alpha_i)$
                & 0.920                 & 0.815             \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
\note
The displayed standard errors are robust and clustered at country level. Level of statistical significance of coefficients:
\item[***]  (\SI{1}{\%}),
\item[**]   (\SI{5}{\%}),
\item[*]    (\SI{10}{\%})
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

From table \ref{tab: my important table} follows \dots
\end{document}
```

- the package `siunitx` is used for `S` columns  , where numbers are aligned at decimal points
- for horizontal lines are used rules defined in the package `booktabs`. thickness of rules in the case if the default values not match your expectations, it can be change as for example `\toprule[2pt]` or `\midrule[2pt]`
- for table notes is used `threeparttablex` which enable to write caption in width of table, `\note` below table and description of `\tnote`s in table (used for statistical significance of value with `**` and `***`)

Comment: yes you got the point I want a table more or less like it! but I'd like to have it centered in the middle of the page and with line separation for each row/column while having bold/bigger lines where you left them.

Comment: @federica, table is simple to center as you wish ... please consider my comments below your question. otherwise i can't finish my answer

Comment: I don't know how I can add a picture. However, I want it like in excel with all the lines that delimits cells and the text centered in the cell

Comment: i do not need picture, i need complete but small document as i wrote in commend below your question. now the my answer is complete and it is according to my taste how such table should look.

Comment: ok but the last line of the table  is not present in the latex text format : The displayed standard errors are robust and clustered at country level. Level of statistical significance of coefficients: ***(1%), **(5%), *(10%)